# Get path to current Windows SDK and C++ RT from within CMake at configure time

Tags: windows, winapi, cmake, msvcrt

Is there a way to get the current linker path from within a CMake script at configure time?

Specifically, when my main CMakeLists.txt is run
(using one of the Visual Studio generatures),
I'm looking for a way to extract the path to the windows SDK
and to the compiler's standard library, so I can pass it to a nested CMake script
using `execute_command`, which utilizes a different generator.
It seems `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` gets set to an absolute path,
from which I could reverse-engineer the path e.g. to msvcrt, but that feels fragile.
For the windows SDK, I'm aware of `CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION`,
which can be combined to a full path using some additional knowledge,
but that involves hard-coded paths at the moment.

I'm happy about any hints. It's amazing how many hours and days I loose every time
I need to do something in CMake that hasn't been hard-coded into the CMake source.

Comment: The `CMAKE_LINKER` variable will be set after CMake identifies your compiler during the configure stage. This gives the path to the linker, but will also only be a relative path to the msvcrt directory. You can print out the path to verify it is what you're looking for: `message(STATUS ${CMAKE_LINKER})`.

Comment: You could use [`find_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) to search for a specific msvcrt library in a path relative to the linker/compiler path, to verify you are working in the correct MSVC RT directory. I'm not aware of a CMake variable that directly provides the full path to the compiler's standard library.

Comment: It's probably best to discover the available Windows SDK's yourself, and choose one that matches your requirements. [FindWindowsSDK.cmake](https://github.com/rpavlik/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindWindowsSDK.cmake) implements this functionality.